# Which mobile browsers support "connectionless push" as described in the EventSource specification?

Tags: server-sent-events

In the EventSource specification:
  http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource

There is a section titled:  Connectionless push and other features

Does anyone know if this is actively developed / supported on applicable browsers?  If so who is leveraging this feature of the spec?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reached out to Ian Hickson (author of the eventsource rfc).  He's given me permission to repost his answer here:

> "I haven't heard of any implementations. That section was added by
>   request from some network-associated handset vendors a few years ago.
>   Since then, the landscape has changed quite a bit and networks and
>   handset vendors don't work as closely together."